# No HO pulse on IR2184 in half h-bridge

Tags: driver

I am unable to get any output on HO pin of IR2184 high side gate driver when I tried to drive a half H bridge.

Vcc is around 12-15V, input to IC is around 8V square wave, bootstrap capacitor voltage is observed to be around 8V. I m able to get LO pin output.

Comment: Have you followed the typical connection scheme given in the datasheet? What MOSFETs and component values did you use?

Comment: Without a schematic, how can we help you?

Answer (score 3):

The type of MOSFETs typically used with a 600V driver chip like that require 10V to be turned on fully, so there is a undervoltage lockout feature provided to disable MOSFET drive when the supply voltage is too low:

[image]

You should be able to get just enough voltage with a 12-15V supply, but remember you cannot have 100% drive high- it needs both MOSFETs to be present and to drive the lower MOSFET on regularly to refresh the bootstrap supply (so duty cycle must be less than 100%). If the lower MOSFET 'on' voltage is too high you may not get there, but normally you'd choose a MOSFET with < 1V Vds(on) at the kind of very low supply voltages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Spehro Pefhany's  answer is valid, and helped me a lot. I'd like to add that contrary to the schema in the datasheet, VS must be grounded when the HO is low  . This is either done by conecting the source of the High side mosfet to the drain of the low side (when the HO is low the low side is on and grounds the VS) or by some other mean.
source :
http://www.irf.com/technical-info/designtp/dt04-4.pdf